# Conditionally save response in Gatling

Tags: load-testing, dsl, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a use case where response from an API should be saved based on the existence of a session variable. Let us assume my session variable is "sampleSession". I need some thing like this:

```
.exec(
        grpc("Client getSomething")
          .rpc(some.someApi)
          .payload(session => session("sample").as[sample])
          .header(ReqIdHeader)(Random.alphanumeric take 30 mkString "")
          .check(statusCode.saveAs("gRPCStatusCode"))
          .check(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
          .doIf("${sampleSession.exists()}"){
             .extract(Option(_))(_ saveAs "Response")
           }
      )
```

I know this doesn't work, but just to give an idea of the requirement. Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via `checkIf`. Like this:

```
checkIf("${sampleSession.exists()}") {
          jsonPath("$..foo").saveAs("foo")
        }
```